# Vue-router do not push to the given name

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

In my project, my routes:

```
const routes = [{
  path: '/',
  meta: {
    title: ''
  },
  component: (resolve) => require(['./views/index.vue'], resolve),
  children: [
    {
      path: 'a',
      name: 'a',
      title:'a',
      component: (resolve) => require(['./views/a/a.vue'], resolve)
    },
    {
      path: 'b',
      name: 'b',
      title:'b',
      component: (resolve) => require(['./views/b/b.vue'], resolve),
      children: [
        {
          path: 'c',
          name: 'c',
          title:'c',
          component: (resolve) => require(['./views/b/ccc.vue'], resolve)
        },
      ]
    },

  ]
}];
```

I have `index.vue`, `a.vue`, `b.vue`, and `c.vue` components in my project.

I have a `<Menu>` in my `index.vue` template:

```
<Menu mode="horizontal"  active-name="1" @on-select="select_item">
    <MenuItem name="a">
      <Icon type="ios-paper"></Icon>
      go to a
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem name="b">
      <Icon type="ios-people"></Icon>
      go to b
    </MenuItem>

    <MenuItem name="c">
      <Icon type="settings"></Icon>
      go to c
    </MenuItem>
  </Menu>
```

you see the Menu `@on-select` bind to `select_item`method, and in the script's methods it return the name, and push to the route by name:

```
  select_item(name){
    console.log(name)

    this.$router.push({name: name})
  }
```

I click the MenuItem `go to a` and `go to b` all works fine, but when I click the `go to c`, it do not work.

I checked my code, but I do't know where is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is nested route in your `b` and `c`:

```
{
  path: 'b',
  name: 'b',
  title:'b',
  component: (resolve) => require(['./views/b/b.vue'], resolve),
  children: [
    {
      path: 'c',
      name: 'c',
      title:'c',
      component: (resolve) => require(['./views/b/ccc.vue'], resolve)
    },
  ]
},
```

the `index.vue`'s `<router-view>` is the top export of the component, which in your routes are `/a` and `/b`. the `/b/c` should in your `b.vue`'s `<router-view>`.

To solve your issue, you should put your

```
    {
      path: 'c',
      name: 'c',
      title:'c',
      component: (resolve) => require(['./views/b/ccc.vue'], resolve)
    },
```

as the same level as the route `a` and route `b`.

or, you should add the `<router-view/>` in your `b.vue`, you can see the effect.